# Microsoft Access Query - Merging two queries into one

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Using the query wizard, I built two different queries doing similar functionalities that I am trying to combine into one query. I have two tables (same structure) that I am matching to find duplicates:

1. **Query #1** is as follows (Include ALL records from Table 1 and only those records from Table 2 where the joined fields are equal are applied to all the columns below):

   ```
   Match Table 1 Column 3  to Table 2 Column 3
   Match Table 1 Column 4  to Table 2 Column 4
   Match Table 1 Column 5  to Table 2 Column 5
   Match Table 1 Column 7  to Table 2 Column 7
   ```

   If all of those columns from Table 1 match what’s in Table 2, it will identify the duplicates (I bring in Table 2 Column 7 which will show the duplicates I am looking for).
2. **Query #2** is as follows (Include ALL records from Table 1 and only those records from Table 2 where the joined fields are equal are applied to all the columns below):

   ```
   Match Table 1 Column 3  to Table 2 Column 3
   Match Table 1 Column 4  to Table 2 Column 4
   Match Table 1 Column 5  to Table 2 Column 5
   Match Table 1 Column 8  to Table 2 Column 8
   ```

   My second query has the same 3 columns, except the last column is different.

   If all of those columns from Table 1, match what’s in Table 2, it will identify the duplicates (I bring in Table 2 Column 7/8 which will show the duplicates I am looking for).

What I am trying to do:

Add an `OR` statement for the query to show both duplicates on matches for Columns 8 and Columns 7. Such as if Table 1 Column 7 matches Table 2 Column 7 OR Table 1 Column 8 matches Table 2 Column 8, show the duplicates.

Would this require a `UNION` query?

Here is the query for one of them:

```
SELECT TABLE1.COLUMN_3, TABLE1.COLUMN_4, TABLE1. COLUMN_7, 
       TABLE2.COLUMN_7, TABLE1.COLUMN_5
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 
  ON  (TABLE1.COLUMN_7 = TABLE2.COLUMN_7) 
  AND (TABLE1.COLUMN_3 = TABLE2.COLUMN_3) 
  AND (TABLE1.COLUMN_4 = TABLE2.COLUMN_4) 
  AND (TABLE1.COLUMN_5 = TABLE2.COLUMN_5);
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using (someone with your reputation should know that).  Sample data and desired results would also be a big help.

Comment: Bit hard to understand the logic, but no problem nesting brackets with AND and OR to give whatever you want. Also possibly use EXISTS if you want to find duplicate, or a full join if you only want to return the duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given SQL will not run because of spaces in table and column names.
This example eliminates those spaces.

```
SELECT
     Table1.Column3 , Table2.Column3
    ,Table1.Column4 , Table2.Column4
    ,Table1.Column5 , Table2.Column5
    ,Table1.Column7 , Table2.Column7
    ,Table1.Column8 , Table2.Column8

From      Table1 
Left Join Table2  
On

(        Table1.Column3 = Table2.Column3
 AND     Table1.Column4 = Table2.Column4
 AND     Table1.Column5 = Table2.Column5
 AND  (  Table1.Column7 = Table2.Column7
      OR Table1.Column8 = Table2.Column8
      )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create query 3; add Q1 and Q2 - join them on F7.  This will result in all matches of that field.

Create query 4; add Q1 and Q2 - join them on F8.  This will result in all matches of that field.

You now have 2 data sets with those matches (you call duplicates).  Then the decision is how to present/display.  If you need them in a single record set - write those into a single common temp table.  But otherwise you can easily present them together as sub reports/forms.